# Using pointers to pass a value from scanf() into main()

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

The below code works fine. It allows a user to enter a `float` value called `error` getting it saved through the `function error_user();`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float error_user ();

int main(void)
{
    float error;

    printf("What error do you want?\n");

    error=error_user ();

    printf("%f\n", error);

    return 0;
}

float error_user ()
{
    float error;
    scanf("%f", &error);
    return error;
}
```

However, the below function does not work. I am trying to achieve the same result with the only difference that I want to pass the value with pointers. How can I achieve this in this second case? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void error_user (float *error);

int main(void)
{
    float error;

    printf("What error do you want?\n");

    error_user (&error);

    printf("%f\n", error);

    return 0;
}

void error_user (float *error)
{
    scanf("%f", &error);
}
```

Comment: In the second version, `error` already has type `float *`, so you don’t need to use the `&` operator in the `scanf` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in the second example, `error` is of type `float *` there is a type mismatch between conversion specifier and relative argument at the `scanf()` call in the `error_user` function, if you use `&error`.

`&error` is of type `float**`, but the `%f` conversion specifier expects an argument of type `float*`.

Providing an argument of wrong type invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Use `error` instead of `&error`.

---

This is an issue a compiler usually warn you about without additional compiler flags invoked. For example gcc:

> "*warning: format `'%f'` expects argument of type `'float *'`, but argument 2 has type `'float **'` [`-Wformat=`]*"

You should either update or swap your compiler to a standard-compliant one or stop to ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @John Bode below is the corrected code. Paraphrasing him: "In the second version, error already has type float *, so you don’t need to use the & operator in the scanf call."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void error_user (float *error);

int main(void)
    {   
        float error;

        printf("What error do you want?\n");

        error_user (&error);

        printf("%f\n", error);

        return 0;
    }

void error_user (float *error)
    {   
        scanf("%f", error);
    }
```